# ¿Cómo iterar un dataframe, de 2 en 2 columnas en Python usando Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, bucles, dataframe

Disculpen, necesito colocar "/" a los datos de las columnas pares, a partir de la columna 6, 8, 10, etc... dentro de un dataframe, como sigue:

```
   [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] ...
[0] 1   1   0   0   2   0   C/  C   B/  A   D/  ...
[1] 1   1   0   0   2   0   C/  D   B/  B   C/  ...
[2] 1   1   0   0   2   0   C/  A   B/  C   B/  ...
[3] 1   1   0   0   2   0   C/  C   B/  D   B/  ...
[4] 1   1   0   0   2   0   C/  C   B/  B   A/  ...
...
```

He intentado esta función de Pandas: `df[6] = df[6].astype(str) + '/'`
Pero quiero que aplique a todo el dataframe, he intentado esto:

`for i, r in df.iteritems():`

`df[i] = df[i].astype(str) + '/ '`

Sin embargo me lo coloca en todas las columnas, y sólo lo quiero desde la columna 6, y en las columnas pares. Si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia se lo agradecería mucho.

Muchas gracias, saludos!

Comment: has probado con `apply()`??

Comment: Lo acabo de resolver aplicando iloc(), y .astype)(srt) + '/' y seleccionando las columnas pares, partí el dataframe en columnas pares e impares y las uní utilizando .concat(), finalmente reordené los indices de las columnas y listo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Sería bueno que añadas tu respuesta para que así otros con problemas similares puedan aprender a resolverlos